# Google Analytics API: export data everyone session

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to get these data from Google Analytics https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

How can I do it? Tried through the Reporting API, did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). What have you tried, exactly, and what happened?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, at least not for the more "exotic" fields (fullVisitorId, Nr. of session etc), at least not via the Reporting API). As the title of the linked page suggests this requires integration with Google's BigQuery product which is only available for GA360 clients.

You can of course get the more mundane dimensions and metrics (i.e. the ones that are accessible via the interface), but I don't suppose your are talking about that (and if you do you should show us what you tried so far).

Comment: Reporting API for some reason summarizes the data( There is such a product "owox" they get all these fields. How do they do it?